# Implementing 2 linked lists in java without pointers

Tags: java, linked-list

I am facing problems while trying to implement 2 linked lists in my Java code.

If I declare my "head" variables in main and pass them to any function, they could not be modified by that function as the referencing variable would be local to that function.

But if I make them class variables, the called function could not know which of the 2 "head" variables I am referring to.

This problem could be easily solved in C language by passing double pointers in functions so that the local variable can modify the passed variable but how to solve this problem in Java? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pointers aren’t used in Java**

Defines the attribute at the class level and don't use it in the signature of your methods, or return the value of your function to the original variable.

```
 public class MyClass{

      private string value;

      public myFunction(){
        value = toto; // this will change the value of the attribute directly
      }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
           MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
           myClass.myFunction(); // The new value is saved at the class level
      }
 }
```

or

public class MyClass{

```
       public String myFunction(String value){
          value = "toto";
          return value; // The value modified is return back to the caller
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
           String myValue = myClass.myFunction(myvalue); // The new value is saved
       }
 }
```

Comment: I think returning changed variable back to the calling function would be best approach. Thanks.